# Может ли звук быть протяжённым?

Tags: выбор-слов, стилистика, семантика, литература

У меня вопрос: может ли звук быть *протяжённым*, или следует применять исключительно слово *протяжный*? Имеется в виду описание длительности определённого звука в предложении, в котором нет возможности применить слово "протяжный", но можно применить слово "протяжённый". Будет ли это правильным, или звук не может быть протяжённым?

Прилагаю строчку, где задействовано это слово: "Я услышал за спиною: обволакивает тьмою, наполняет кровь тоскою протяжённый волчий вой".

Comment: В строке, которая приведена, ЭТО слово не задействовано. Где вой, и где звук... Хорошо, если вой в первую сотню синонимов входит. В словаре Н. Абрамова он дан лишь опосредованно через голос.

Answer (score 2):

Как поэтическая вольность, возможно, это и допустимо - в интересах ритма строки или рифмы. В примере воспринимается как обыгрывание слова "протяжный" (в значении "очень протяжный" - добавлением преувеличительного суффикса, по аналогии с просторечными "огроменный" и "большенный").

В обычной же речи "протяжённый" характеризует занимаемое пространство, продольный размер, а не растянутость звука во времени, поэтому заставит думать о волновых фронтах, о стоячих волнах и прочих акустических премудростях; смысл "протяжности" звука при этом искажается.

**P.S**. Практика употребления. В "нац. корпусе" сочетание "протяжённый звук" не находится вообще" (**0** - при 28 случаев "протяжного звука"). Гугл сразу предлагает искать "протяжный (звук)", сочтя запрос ошибочным, но при некоторой настойчивости можно найти такое сочетание; практически везде прилагательное спутано по значению с "протяжный". В случае *волков* можно себе представить протяжённый волновой фронт, но здесь явно обыграно устойчивое сочетание "протяжный вой".

Answer (score 2):

***Протяженный звук*** ― это звук длинный, растянутый во времени. Поэтому смысл сочетания вполне ясен. Есть такие понятия, как протяженный период, протяженный интервал.

У слов  ***протяжный*** и ***протяженный*** разные оттенки значений. ***Протяженный*** ― растянутый во времени или в пространстве, ***протяжный*** ― длительно звучащий; тягучий.

Сочетание *протяженный звук* встречается не часто, но заменить на *протяжный* его нельзя. Например: Я делаю видео. **Нужен протяженный звук падающего снаряда не меньше 7 секунд.** Кто знает, где скачать?

Comment: Звук «длинный»... Разве не долгий? Ко времени и  пространству один и тот же набор слов не подходит. Если говорят «протяжённый», то с довеском — по времени.

Comment: Может быть, долгий звук - это лучше, но длинный  звук тоже говорят, например: Торелли издал какой-то непонятный длинный звук... (К. Паустовский). "Довесок", думаю, не нужен. Мы же говорим: долго тянется время, а звук может быть протяженным только во времени.

Answer (score 1):

> Может ли звук быть протяжённым?

В словарях такого значения у слова *протяжённый* встретить мне не удалось.

Но в поэзии встречается. См. у **Бориса Слуцкого**:

> *Звук прекрасный, **звук протяженный**,*
>
> *Звук печальной и чистой волны:*
>
> *Так поют солдатские жены*
>
> *В первый год многолетней войны.*

Встречается и в качестве [**музыкального термина**](https://books.google.ru/books?id=LMxfAAAAMAAJ&q=%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA%22&dq=%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwimubjNvqDbAhVFM5oKHTfyCT4Q6AEIKTAA):

> *В таких случаях нередко происходит замена одного гласного звука другим - тем, который лучше звучит. Так, М.Д. Михайлов, постепенно
>   понижая **протяженный звук**, пел "не раз в бою кровавом ужас смерти
>   сеял мой бу[лот]".*

И в художественной литературе (аналогично словосочетанию из примера к вопросу). См. у **Леонида Андреева**:

> *Долгую зиму Пармен слушал по ночам волчий **протяженный вой**, пока не подошла весна, принесшая с собой жизнь для всей природы.*

Answer (score 0):

*Я услышал за спиною:

обволакивает тьмою,

наполняет кровь тоскою

**протяжённый** волчий **вой**.*

Мне кажется, что Вы не совсем правильно задали вопрос: в тексте — **протяжённый вой**, а спрашиваете Вы про **протяженный звук**.
Существует протяжный (или протяженный?) крик — это [**вой**](http://%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82.%D1%80%D1%84/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9):

~протяженный крик некоторый животных (волка, собаки, шакала) [Ожегов];
~протяжный крик некоторых животных (волка, собаки, шакала и т. п.); завывание [Ефремова];
~протяжный крик некоторых животных (волка, собаки, шакала) [Ожегов, Шведова].

*Лишь изредка гул от мостов пробежит над водою;

Лишь **крик протяженный** из дальней промчится деревни,

Где в ночь окликается ратная стража со стражей.*
[**А. С. Пушкин. Евгений Онегин**](http://ilibrary.ru/text/436/p.10/index.html)

*Страх навис над Аутрайнкарном. Длинный, **протяженный звук**, барабанящий в уши, слышен был, наверное, до самого Меккара.*
Э. Брин. Ужас клана. Акт I

*Малыш гулял по зоопарку:

Вот клетка с тигром, вот с совой.

Вдруг слышит мальчик звуки драки

И **волчий протяженный вой**.*
[**М. Ставская. Драка в зоопарке**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=VV0wDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT9&lpg=PT9&dq=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9&source=bl&ots=N5fK8-r5Xp&sig=bv2jI2nXaeMVCu86sEBs33j-fds&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIxrSzsKHbAhWOLVAKHcunCS4Q6AEIMDAC#v=onepage&q=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9&f=false)

*Каждое страдание — это бездна затхлой крови, каждый **протяженный вой** страдания — клубы полос, неровных, грубо перемещенных, словно кипящие атомы рождающихся миров...*
Из статьи о картине Э. Мунка "Крик"

*Улетая, огорчённая Мать-Драконица сделала добрый десяток кругов над дворцом, причём издала **протяжённый плач**, способный ввергнуть в волнение и самого хладнокровного из людей-яральцев.*
А. Бреусенко-Кузнецов. Драконы смеются

Мне кажется, что поэту можно так написать — для придания особенного, необычного состояния страха, боли, тоски, безысходности.
Вот, у того же Мунка (под картиной "Отчаяние"):
«Небо вдруг стало кроваво-красным, и я почувствовал взрыв меланхолии, грызущей боли под сердцем. (...) Над сине-черным фьордом и городом лежали кровь и языки пламени. (…) я остался позади, трепеща от страха, и я услышал **бесконечный крик**, пронзающий природу».